# ¿Cómo editar un archivo de un contenedor detenido Docker?

Tags: docker

Cambié una configuración en `mysqld.cnf` dentro del contenedor, ahora el contenedor se inicializa, pero se detiene en un segundo.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

```
user@usaer:~$ sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
37c007e7a916        percona:5.7         "docker-entrypoint..."   3 weeks ago         Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   aprendoo_db
microinformatica@MicroinformaticaDB:~$ sudo docker exec -ti 37c007e7a916 bash
```

> Error response from daemon: Container
>   37c007e7a916b075030d85cbc952db10b559ddb2e1b01f4c84f38e09431ce50e is
>   not running

```
user@user:~$ sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

El servicio se inicia, pero se apaga al segundo. Al parecer da error con la `bind-address`, que está en el archivo `mysqld.cnf`. Como el contenedor está para *MySQL*, al encontrar este error no permite que se que quede levantado el contenedor.

Comment: Hola, debiaras aportar algo de código para que podamos ayudarte, por ahora no contamos con bolas de cristal para saber que es lo que te falla. Pasate por el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: Puedes actualizar el post con el log que genera el contenedor?, intenta con ```docker logs id_container```.

Answer (score 1):

Un contenedor se inicia con el comando que figure en el dockerfile, pero puedes iniciarlo también con un comando si se lo pasas como un parámetro.
Por ejemplo para levantar MySQL de manera que levante automático y me devuelva la terminal (usando el parámetro -d [detach]) ejecutaría:

```
# docker run -d mysql
```

Para levantar el mismo contenedor para mirar dentro o tocar algo lo haría levantando una terminal dentro del contenedor (usando los parámetros -it [interactive, terminal]) y al final indicando el comando que quiero, que es BASH (lo que me proporciona la terminal dentro del contenedor):

```
# docker run -it mysql bash
```

Comment: microinformatica@MicroinformaticaDB:~$ sudo docker run -ti 37c007e7a916 bash
Unable to find image '37c007e7a916:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository 37c007e7a916 not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mediante el gestor de archivos, ami me paso lo mismo, solo que hay archivos que no se pueden modificar directamente, estos son archivos de configuracion referenciados hace de acceso directo, estoy seguro que buscando podras encontrar el archivo al que apunta.

en esta imagen se ve como el archivo my.cnf apunta a mariadb.cnf